# "Address already in use" when trying to start XMPP server

Tags: ubuntu, xmpp

I've been trying to start a pre-compiled executable that launches an XMPP service but to no avail. This is the project where the executable was from http://sourceforge.net/projects/androidpn/.

My setup is a single box (ubuntu server OS) with two IP addresses (lets call them IP1 and IP2). Every time I try to start the XMPP server, I will get an error "Address already in use" from the Java executable. <s>The ports used by XMPP are free and just to be sure, I made sure that Apache only listens to ports on IP1. However, I am still unable to get the XMPP server to start.</s>

Would it be an issue with the way my 2 IP addresses are set up? Or is there something else I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit:**
Thanks to Paul,
`netstat -pant` shows this particular line (5222 is a port used the XMPP server):

`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5222            0.0.0.0:*       LISTEN   14085/citserver`

I am assuming that 0.0.0.0 is referring to all IPs. As I have two IP addresses on this box, would there be a way make citserver/webcit/citadel listen only on the first IP, freeing the same port for the pre-compiled XMPP on the second IP?

p.s. a chunk of the log that describes the error:

```
{INFO } [2012-06-13 11:23:22,578] <org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl> : closing
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ioAcceptor' defined in class path resource [spring-config.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:429)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:728)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:380)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
        at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
        at org.androidpn.server.xmpp.XmppServer.start(XmppServer.java:91)
        at org.androidpn.server.xmpp.XmppServer.<init>(XmppServer.java:76)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
        at org.androidpn.server.starter.ServerStarter.start(ServerStarter.java:82)
        at org.androidpn.server.starter.ServerStarter.main(ServerStarter.java:48)
Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use
        at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:137)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(ServerSocketAdaptor.java:77)
        at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioSocketAcceptor.open(NioSocketAcceptor.java:251)
        at org.apache.mina.transport.socket.nio.NioSocketAcceptor.open(NioSocketAcceptor.java:48)
        at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoAcceptor.registerHandles(AbstractPollingIoAcceptor.java:523)
        at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoAcceptor.access$200(AbstractPollingIoAcceptor.java:65)
        at org.apache.mina.core.polling.AbstractPollingIoAcceptor$Acceptor.run(AbstractPollingIoAcceptor.java:407)
        at org.apache.mina.util.NamePreservingRunnable.run(NamePreservingRunnable.java:64)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
{INFO } [2012-06-13 11:23:22,596] <org.androidpn.server.xmpp.XmppServer> : XmppServer stopped
```

Comment: What OS are you running on?  What ports is the XMPP server intending to listen on?  Have you confirmed they are definitely free with `netstat -an`?

Comment: hi Paul, i'm on ubuntu server. I'm certain as the IP is totally clean. Furthermore, the default ports for XMPP do not clash with any of the ports listed on netstat.

Comment: The XMPP server disagrees with you.  Please [edit] and add the ports XMPP expects to use, along with the results of `sudo netstat -pant`

Comment: i might have spoken too soon. I think my citadel server is listening on a port needed by the XMPP server:
`tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5222            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      14085/citserver`

How do I make citadel/citserver listen on the ports of IP1 only (so that I can use the same ports on IP2)?

Comment: Please update your question to reflect the new query and additional information.